macOS 10.15 Catalina. Include list for TimeMachine
I do backup with TimeMachine but I don't need a bootable backup. In fact I need only a few directories to be back upped. So I have to exclude lots of files and directories. It would be much better to do it with positive (include) list. Everything that isn't on the list get skipped. The Problem is... every time a new directory or app is added it has to be manually excluded. Is there a way to do that with TM?

Seriously: wouldn't it be easier, safer, and more useful, just to back up everything? I've used TM to roll back app versions, recover config files, and all sorts of other stuff.  The comparatively small delta in file size is well worth it for peace of mind. The OS is already excluded by default. Invariably, one day, you're going to want something that you didn't include.
